# Using FOR in Command Line: How to get the parameter's directory?

Tags: windows, command-line, directory

I am trying to do some recursive work for processing images etc, they get copied into a new folder. I only specify the root folder of the input files and there is a whole tree of folders and images inside. If I run the below code, the images all gets copied into the same folder. I.e. they loose the tree-of-folders. Most of these images have the same name, thus it conflicts copying them into a single folder.

This is what I use thats doing the above mentioned:

```
FOR /R "./New" %f IN (*.png) DO (pngcrush -brute -d /ProcessedTiles %f %f)
```

This takes all my PNG's in `./New`, process them and then add the images to `/ProcessedTiles` on my `C://` drive. Very convenient and works well.

Inside `./New` there are many directories such as `./New/5/9` with two images in etc. What I want is to be able to get the file from there (`./New/5/9/25.png`) and when converted have is saved at `/ProcessedTiles/5/6/25.png` instead of the `./ProcessedTiles/25.png` which I get now.

So is there a command line command similar to this:

```
FOR /R "./New" %f IN (*.png) DO (pngcrush -brute -d /ProcessedTiles %f "(%f's directory)+%f")
```

Thank you